# Python Flask Register form - The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, forms, registration

From Flask I keep getting:

> **"*404 not found - Not Found*"**.

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again
I'm sure there is an stupid error, I'm new to python and I have spent some hours trying to understand the problem.

My code:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method =='POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        lastname = form.lastname.data
        email = form.email.data

        # Create DictCursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Execute query
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, lastname, email) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, lastname, email))

        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        # Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('You are now subscribed to the podcast channel', 'success')

        redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

And the regiser form is:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Subscribe</h1>
    {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method="POST" action=="">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.name, class_="form-control")}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.lastname, class_="form-control")}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.email, class_="form-control")}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.confirm, class_="form-control")}}
      </div>
      <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I confirm I can reach directly http://127.0.0.1:5000/register.

Running the app in debug mode, this is what I get:

- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 237-184-388
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1"
  404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /jumbotron.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js HTTP/1
  .1" 404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 40
  4 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js HTTP/1
  .1" 404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 40
  4 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2018 09:11:52] "POST /=%22%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: are you sure you are reaching `http://127.0.0.1:5000/register`?
 Can you run the flask `application.run(debug=True)` and provide the error displayed on the python console,

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Yes, I reach 127.0.0.1:5000/register. I have added the output of the debug to the description

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for reviving a very old question but you need to point the form action to "/register". This makes the form direct take the data to the "/register" route and perform the instructions handled there.

```
<form method="POST" action="/register">
```